# Getting error using \MakeUppercase with tocloft

Tags: table-of-contents, capitalization, tocloft

Trying to use `tocloft` package to customize a table of contents, but I am running into errors using `\MakeUppercase` or `\uppercase` with certain commands, namely `\cftsecfont`.

When I run the following code I get errors suggesting there are missing or extra `}`s. Similar errors when I replace `\MakeUppercase` with `\uppercase`. If I delete that command entirely it runs with no errors.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\bfseries\MakeUppercase}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section Two}
\end{document}
```

Similar errors using `\cftsubsecfont`, etc. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\MakeUppercase` is a command with an argument, not a font changing command.

Answer (score 6):

You can patch the `\l@section` (and friends) macros - they are responsible for setting the section/subsection titles in the ToC - to `\MakeUppercase` the first argument it receives (which includes the number and title):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tocloft,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{tocloft,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% \patchcmd{<cmd>}{<search>}{<replace>}{<success>}{<failure>}
\patchcmd{\l@section}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}% Sections use UPPERCASE in ToC
\patchcmd{\l@subsection}{#1}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{}{}% Subsections use UPPERCASE in ToC
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section One}
\subsection{Subsection}
\section{Section Two}
\end{document}
```

The above patch is suggested based on the construction of `\l@section` (and friends) (from [`tocloft.dtx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tocloft/tocloft.dtx)):

```
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
     % <snip>
     {\cftsecfont #1}\nobreak
     \cftsecfillnum{#2}}%
  \fi}
```

After the patch, `\l@section` resembles

```
\renewcommand*{\l@section}[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
     % <snip>
     {\cftsecfont \MakeUppercase{#1}}\nobreak
     \cftsecfillnum{#2}}%
  \fi}
```

which forces an UPPERCASE title to be set.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. That fixed my uppercase issue, but apparently broke my bibliography. Probably easier for me to just type my section titles in all caps.